# Swing-Library for Android?

Tags: java, android, swing, user-interface

I know that Android uses Java but not a fully compatible runtime library. Creating UIs in Android is done completely different than for normal Desktop Java. Nevertheless that's a really stupid thing in my opinion, very much Java applications out there have to be rewritten for Android (instead of modified only slightly).

So my question: is there some kind of (3rd party) Swing-library available for Android? Means a Java-package that contains Swing-compatible classes so that an existing Swing-Application has to be modified only slightly? It of course can't be 100% compatible but modifying some things that do not exist on Android is much less work than rewriting the whole GUI-part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeNameOne?

Supposed to be very similar to Swing.

Also, in my experience, GWT is somewhat similar to Swing.

Either of these will require a rewrite from Swing though.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way you can use swing in android, because android is not based on JavaSE, while swing is. android uses a special java that is designed to run on [DVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) .

Even if their is no compatibility issue. Swing is used for desktop apps which differ in their UI completely from mobile apps.

So given the above points unfortunately you will have to rewrite the UI again for your software. but on the bright side, android's UI is very simple and fun to work with.
give it sometime and good luck!

**Edit**:
[Comparison between Java SE and Android's Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API)

Comment: It's a special Java VM but Android has Java SE all right.

Comment: it uses many of Java SE libraries but no one says it is "based" on Java SE

Comment: @Alex: "Android has Java SE all right" -- no, it does not. Of the three Java flavors (SE, EE, ME), Android is closest to SE. However, there are many packages missing in their entirety (e.g., Swing, JAX-RPC). Many other packages have only partial implementations (e.g., `java.beans`, `java.awt`).

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you that was a mistake on my part then, I've upvoted the answer then

Answer (score 3):

There is no Swing on Android.  You can always develop a JME application and run it via emulation, but that's as close as it gets.  Unfortunately, in technology, things change all the time, so for programmers, it's a case of "adapt or die."

Comment: I looked, but wasn't able to find an emulators that run on anything past Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Java Swing Desktop Apps can't run on Android (Dalvik VM), but the good news is: **JavaFX as a successor to Swing GUI technology has already been ported to mobile and embedded platform (e.g. Android)**. If you're interested in this, go http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/ for details.

Comment: Free edition of JavaFX on mobile has a nag screen, so it's not ideal for app development